# Is $(z-i)(z+1)$ a polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

Suppose I factorise the polynomial $(z+i)(z-i)(z+1)$ and I'm interested in the remainder term, when I factor $(z+i)$ out?

Is $(z-i)(z+1)$ a polynomial?

Comment: Yes ${{{{{}}}}}$

Comment: It is a polynomial with complex coefficients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure it is, just expand it out:
$$ (z-i)(z+1)=z^2+(1-i)z-i$$

Comment: Alternatively, instead of expanding it out, you could quote the general theorem that the product of any two polynomials (or indeed of any finite number of polynomials) is a polynomial.

Comment: I could, but then again that theorem is just proven both expanding out the polynomial product so it would be a bit pointless considering how easy this is to expand

Comment: I agree that in this case expanding is easy (though I often surprise myself with mistakes even in trivial computations).  Nevertheless, I think it's worth mentioning the general result, because it can be used equally well in other situations where a direct computation would be much less convenient.